# Reactive Extensions (UI) increasing event calls

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I have the below code.

```
this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SelectedDay)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3600))
    .Where(x => SelectedDay != null)
    .ObserveOn(CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher)
    .Subscribe(x => SomeRandomMethod());
```

Throttle is working great and it will not call SomeRandomMethod until x.SelectedDay has stopped changing. However it is calling it for each time that it has changed.

```
So i do this:  
Change,  
Change,  
Wait  
//SomeRandomMethod called 2 times at end of throttle  
Change  
Wait  
//SomeRandomMethod called 3 times
Change  
Change  
Change 
Wait  
//SomeRandomMethod called 6 times.
```

How can i get it to ignore all previous change events and only get the latest at the time throttle has done it's thing.

```
So i would like this:
Change   
Change 
Wait  
//SomeRandomMethod called once
Change  
Wait  
//SomeRandomMethod called once
Change  
Change  
Change 
Wait  
//SomeRandomMethod called once
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you calling this method? You should only be calling it in the Constructor, and only calling it once. Also, here's a better version of the code above:

```
this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SelectedDay)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3600), RxApp.DeferredScheduler)
    .Where(x => SelectedDay != null)
    .Subscribe(x => SomeRandomMethod());
```

Comment: ha ha, of course. Feel such a dumb-ass. 'RxApp.DeferredScheduler' is a nice touch too. Many thanks.

Comment: @Kohan No worries, it's a common mistake. Try to think of RxUI calls as describing how things are related - it's a declaration, like a XAML Binding.